# Display image stored as blob using GWT Jersy Rest

Tags: java, rest, gwt, base64

I am not able to display an image stored as blob returned by a rest service :

This is the rest service code that returns the blob stored image coded into base64 :

```
@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces("image/jpeg")
public Response getFile() {
    String base64 = getStringImage();
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) base64);
    return response.build();
}

String getStringImage() {
    try {
        AnounceService anounceService =                          (AnounceService)getApplicationContext().getBean("AnounceService");
        Blob imageBlob =  anounceService.getStgImage();
        int blobLength = (int)imageBlob.length();
        byte[] buff = imageBlob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
        String base64=Base64Utils.toBase64(buff);
        return base64;
    } catch (Exception exc) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the gwt client code that fails to display the image returned by the above rest code :
String url = "root/api/image/get";
final RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);Image img;

builder.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {

```
            public void onResponseReceived(final Request request, final Response response) {
                    if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.SC_OK) {
                        final HTML imageHolder = new HTML();
                        String base64 = response.getText();
                        String imgTag = "<img src='data:image/gif;base64,"+base64+"' />'";
                        imageHolder.setHTML(imgTag);

                        RootPanel.get().add(imageHolder);

                    }

                }
```

There is no error triggered, but I don't see any image displayed in the browser.

Comment: Should it really be @Produces("image/jpeg") when you're treating the response as a string? Try changing it 'text/plain'